# How do I call method based on one parameter in ascending order?

Tags: javascript

I am calling a method multiple times:

```
displayA(aTotal, sectorTotalValue, templateItems);
displayB(bTotal, sectorTotalValue, templateItems);
...many more times
```

I want to call these in ascending order based on `aTotal` , `bTotal` and so on.

So if `bTotal > aTotal` then I want them to be called in this order:

```
displayB(bTotal, sectorTotalValue, templateItems);
displayA(aTotal, sectorTotalValue, templateItems);
```

And if `bTotal < aTotal` then I want them to be called in this order:

```
displayA(aTotal, sectorTotalValue, templateItems);
displayB(bTotal, sectorTotalValue, templateItems);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: *if `bTotal > bTotal`* — that makes no sense

Comment: And why are you calling `displayB` twice, with the same parameters?

Comment: Made a mistake in copy & paste. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach based on putting the variables into an array and custom sorting:

```
const displayCalls = [
     { total: aTotal, func: displayA },
     { total: bTotal, func: displayB },
];

//sort array to put highest total first
displayCalls.sort((call1, call2) => call2.total - call1.total);

//call each one in order
displayCalls.forEach(call => {
    call.func(call.total, sectorTotalValue, templateItems);
});
```